# Get all directories in directory that has a numeric name with powershell

Tags: powershell, directory

I will start off by saying I am new to powershell...
I can get all the directories in a specified directory but I need to only get the directories that their names are numeric. Example:

```
1 - include
2 - include
3 - include
10 - include
LastFailed - exclude
```

I also will need to order them in sequential order for later processing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path ..\..\..\builds -Attributes D 

foreach($D in $Dirs)
{
    Write-Host $D.Name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of just the folders that have numeric names, you can do this:

```
$Path = '..\..\..\builds'
$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Attributes D | 
        Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d+$' } | 
        Sort-Object
$Dirs
```

This code above uses the Where-Object clause to filter out only the folders that have a numeric-only name. 
It does this by using the `-match` operator and the regular expression `^\d+$` where:

```
`^`  --> start at the beginning of the line
`\d` --> look for numeric values (0-9)
`+`  --> there must be 1 or more numeric values present
`$`  --> the end of the string
```

Instead of `\d` it could also have been written using `[0-9]`
The code ends with `Sort-Object` because the OP wants the list of folders sorted.
because we do not tell what property to sort on here, Powershell defaults to the Name.

The above will produce a list like:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                            
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                            
d-----        18-8-2018     16:13                1                                                                                                                               
d-----        18-8-2018     16:13                10                                                                                                                              
d-----        18-8-2018     16:13                2                                                                                                                               
d-----        18-8-2018     16:13                5
```

As you can see, the list **is** sorted by property Name, but.. the numbers were treated as strings, so '10' follows '1'.

What we most likely want to do here is to have the Sort-Object treat the names as real Numbers, not strings.
To fix that we add the `Select-Object` cmdlet in order to create our own objects with properties we need.

We can get standard properties of the DirInfo object that is coming through the pipeline, AND it is possible to create a new *calculated* property.

Here I add the calculated property called `SortIndex` that is simply the numeric value converted from the Name, which we will then use for the numeric sort:

```
$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Attributes D | 
        Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d+$' } | 
        Select-Object -Property FullName, Name, LastWriteTime, @{Name = 'SortIndex'; Expression = {[int]$_.Name} } |
        Sort-Object -Property SortIndex
$Dirs
```

Now it produces an array of objects that when printed to console looks like this:

```
FullName   Name LastWriteTime      SortIndex
--------   ---- -------------      ---------
D:\Temp\1  1    18-8-2018 16:13:22         1
D:\Temp\2  2    18-8-2018 16:13:25         2
D:\Temp\5  5    18-8-2018 16:13:28         5
D:\Temp\10 10   18-8-2018 16:13:31        10
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add some explanation too. If future readers don't know about regexes, the answer is hard to understand.

Comment: @vonPryz You're right. It was getting late, but my former code-only answer was too blunt. I have now edited the answer to explain.

Comment: Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `Where-Object` to filter your collection:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path ..\..\..\builds -Directory |
    Where-Object -Property Name -Match '\d'
```

This operation uses regex to match the digit class.

---

If you meant you only want the directory names that *start* with a digit, you can use an *anchor*:

```
'^\d'
```

and lastly, you can sort them with `Sort-Object`:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path ..\..\..\builds -Directory |
    Where-Object -Property Name -Match '^\d' |
    Sort-Object -Property Name
```

---

You can further enhance this sort by being explicit about the starting digit:

```
-Property {[int]($_.Name -split '[^\d]')[0]}
```

In this context, we're splitting on the first non-digit character and capturing the first fragment that was split off (which should be the number represented as a string, so we cast to an integer).